# Is there a way to mass create \newcommands?

Tags: macros

At the beginning of my documents, I tend to have a long list of macros I've defined, which looks like

```
\newcommand{\Cat}{\textup{Cat}}

\newcommand{\Dog}{\textup{Dog}}

\newcommand{\Grape}{\textup{Grape}}

...
```

etc. Is there a way I can compress this into a single command, giving a list of words to turn into macros, e.g. something like the following fake code?

```
list = {Cat,Dog,Grape, ... }

for all elements e of the list, \newcommand{\e}{\textup{e}}
```

Comment: You can define `\newcommand\Example[1]{\textup{Example#1}}` then use `\Example{A}`...

Comment: ExampleA etc is just a stand-in for a random word like Sym, QCoh, etc. Could you write down how to do it for an arbitrary list? I've edited the question to be clearer.

Comment: it is normally not a good idea to define lots of new commands, you easily clash with existing command names. Also this only works for names like Dog and Grape but will fails for `Bär` or `x-ray`. Why don't you simply define an editor shortcut which surrounds a word with `\textup`?

Comment: There are a lot of symbols that I type really often that would save me a lot of time (and make my files easier to read) with specific commands.

Comment: Ulrike's point is that in most editors you can create shortcuts to save that time.  And defining lots of custom commands usually makes a document harder for others to read.

Comment: Ah fair enough. At least TeXMaker only allows 10 shortcuts, and it's useful for me to have ~100 of these \textup macros defined.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\massdefine}{m}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \cs_new_protected:cpn { ##1 } { \textup{##1} }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\massdefine{Cat,Dog,Grape}
```

The function `\clist_map_inline:nn` does a loop on the items in the given list; in each cycle, the item is denoted by `#1` (here `##1` because we're in a definition). With `\cs_new_protected:cpn` the first argument is transformed in a control sequence name before performing the command definition.

Suppose that, for better evidence in the document, you want instead to define `\CAT` and so on, you can modify into

```
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\massdefine}{m}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \cs_new_protected:cpn { \str_uppercase:n { ##1 } } { \textup{##1} }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\massdefine{Cat,Dog,Grape}
```

so `\CAT` will do `\textup{Cat}`.

On the other hand, doing

```
\newcommand{\KW}[1]{\textup{#1}}
```

and using

```
\KW{Cat}
```

is probably better in the long run.

---

Answering the followup in the comments:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\massdefine}{m}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \cs_new_protected:cpx { ##1 } { \exp_not:N \textup { \tl_range:nnn { ##1 } { 1 } { -2 } } }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\massdefine{Cat,Dog,Grape}

\begin{document}

A \Cat

A \Dog

A \Grape

\end{document}
```

The last letter is gobbled at definition time using `\cs_new_protected:cpx` that expands the contents, so `\tl_range:nnn` can do its job; the second argument is the starting point, the third argument the end point and `-2` denotes the penultimate item (second from the end).

[image]

For complex treatment of these keywords, define your own formatter.

```
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentCommand{\genericformatter}{m}{%
  \textbf{\textup{#1}}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\massdefine}{m}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \cs_new_protected:cpx { ##1 } { \genericformatter { \tl_range:nnn { ##1 } { 1 } { -2 } } }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\massdefine{Cat,Dog,Grape}

\begin{document}

A \Cat

A \Dog

A \Grape

\itshape A \Cat

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to modify the ##1 entry (for instance removing the last letter, so that typing \Grape gives you \textup{Grap})?

Comment: @Pulcinella There are several variations possible. But your comment seems more on how to *add* something to the command name. A real use case would be better for understanding your need.

Comment: Sorry, to be precise: is there any way to modify your code so that writing {\Cat, \Dog, \Grape, ... } in the main body of the TeX file will give {\textup{Ca}, \textup{Do}, \textup{Grap}, ... } ?

Comment: @Pulcinella See edit

Comment: Thank you so much, this was really helpful!

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you again, but do you know whether it is possible to make the list *both* \textbf and \textup ? I've tried fiddling with the code/finding documentation about LaTeX coding but can't get it to work.

Comment: @Pulcinella For more complex things, it's better to define your own formatter. See edit.

Comment: Thanks so much for spending the time to answer my questions :)

Answer (score 5):

Using `\clist_map_inline:nn` from `expl3` can do this easily:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_map_inline:nn { Cat, Dog, Umbrella }
  {
    \exp_args:Nc \newcommand {#1} { \textup {#1} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\textit{\Cat\ and \Dog}.
\end{document}
```

But I'd prefer using some markup for this instead as [@PhelypeOleinik recommended](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/651268/is-there-a-way-to-mass-create-newcommands#comment1623203_651268).

Comment: I see you don't like grapes ;-)

Comment: Umbrellas are not good to eat

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I could sent you some Schokoladenregenschirme when it gets cooler.

Answer (score 3):

It almost sounds like acronyms or a glossary, that is acronym commands. Or keywords.

Depending on the length of the symbols, if the short-version/long-version ratio approach works to save typing, you could use a property list.

[image: b for bear]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand { \kwloadaprop } { +m } { 

    \prop_gset_from_keyval:Nn 
            \g_tmpa_prop
            { #1 }
}



\NewDocumentCommand { \KW } { m }
 {
            \tl_clear:N \l_tmpa_tl
            
                    \prop_get:NnNTF
                            \g_tmpa_prop
                            { #1 }
                            \l_tmpa_tl
                            { 
                           >>
                            \text_uppercase:n { \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl }
                           <<                           
                             }
                            { #1 ~ not ~ found }


 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\kwloadaprop{
cat=cat
,dog=dog
,grape=grape
,sr=Schokoladenregenschirme 
,b=Bär or x-ray
,num1=123-4
}

\begin{document}


b $\mapsto$ \KW{b}

num1 $\mapsto$ \KW{num1}

sr $\mapsto$ \KW{sr}

b2 $\mapsto$ \KW{b2}


\end{document}
```